# Purpose of Gulp and Grunt

Tags: angular, configuration, gruntjs, gulp, asp.net-core

Recently i came to know about angular2 and i have been working with it for past one month then when i try to run it in my .net core application when i see online for how to configure they told that i have to use Gulp or Grunt that makes me curius and when i run the demo project on line i come to know that its what extracting me the packages and my '**Typescript file to js**', why do i have to convert my Typescript 'ts' file to 'js formet' file, i didn't need see it happening when i run the file using the online library file..

So could you help me with, what's the purpose of gulp and grunt, and is there any possible way to run my angular 2 application in Visual Studio with out using gulp or grunt

please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grunt and Gulp are task runners. So, you can create tasks to do things like:

- Compile your css using sass/less;
- Get all your javascripts files and create a single minified js file;
- Run your tests;
- Copy images from a source folder to a public folder;

You don't need them to develop your web app, but they make our lifes easier.

You may not see the benefits right now, but I recommend you to choose one of them for your project.

I also created a simple [tutorial](https://github.com/fabriciokoch/AspnetcoreAngular) that shows how to create a simple App with C# WebAPI and AngularJS. It's not Angular2, but there, you can see how to setup the environment for the client tools (GruntJS, NPM, ...) and how to use them.

EDIT:

You can avoid NPM, Grunt and other client tools (I'm not sure if you need something specific for TypeScript, because I've never used it).

You can refer to a online library (CDN) like this (Example for AngularJS 1.5.8):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can download it and place it inside wwwroot folder of your project and create a reference like this:

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
```

Note that with this, you have to know where is the lib you want to refer or download it.

If you use NPM, you just create a `package.json` file like this:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.7",
    "angular-i18n": "1.5.7",
    "angular-loading-bar": "0.9.0",
    //more dependencies here...
  }
}
```

Visual Studio downloads these dependencies automatically and place them in the `node_modules` folder. We have also "auto-complete" feature in this file, so, just type "CTRL+SPACE" and you can see some suggestions.

After that, you can use Grunt to move the files from `node_modules` to `wwwroot` or copy and paste them manually.

Like I said before, with these tools it's easier.

Comment: Thanks @FabricioKoch,
but is there a way to use online library file without using the npm or gulp to run my project in **IIS for asp.net or any other server** to run my angular project

Comment: Yes i get it 
but my app files "**Typescript**" files are also moved to wwwroot folder while am running grunt task and converting my "TS" formet file to "JS" is there a way that my application will run without that because the last time i check its not and getting the error that my files are missing

Comment: You have to "compile" your Typescript file to get a javascript file that a browser can understand. VisualStudio has an option to "compile on save" in "tools->options->text editor->typescript->project->general". This option should work, but I've never used typescript before, and I don't know where it will place the js files.